# Limiting an iOS app to installation on only one device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app written in Swift where I want to limit each account to one device only – what is a way that I could go about limiting this access? I'm using Firebase and have a login system but the login system is not linked to Firebase Auth.

Comment: Is it Enterprise app or it's planned to be released on AppStore?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273108/1242673

Comment: @user28434 it's more of a beta test

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410391/how-to-handle-multiple-connections-of-the-same-user-on-firebase and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321234/how-to-prevent-simultaneous-logins-of-the-same-user-with-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that also works, that I found through research, is to store the uid of a device in the database used in the app (or in NSUserDefaults) via `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString`. Then, when a user logs in, compare the uuid with the device's uuid and take the appropriate action.

This is not foolproof – if the user uninstalls the app and re-installs it, they will be assigned a different uuid. But in general, this is the best approach.

Comment: is there a unique identifier, that does not change, which can be used?

Answer (score 1):

After login the use generate the token and save them into dataBase. And send this token in header when you hit any other API. If new same use login on other device, update the token in data base .

Now you check this token is same or not if not then send repose code 401 and logout the user.