# Prevent Login on more than one device

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an app in C#, in this program I want to prevent the user from being able to login on more than one device without first performing authorization on the old device or requesting a change of device via the registered email. I'm using Firebase as my database

So far I've seen something about DeviceID but I didn't get it right and I don't know if that's the way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's nothing built into Firebase Authentication for this, as that tool merely verifies the credentials that a user enters. But you can build a solution on top of Firebase Authentication. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732982, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385780, and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+Prevent+Login+on+more+than+one+device